# Синтаксис Java: "->"

Tags: java

Что обозначает это выражение?

```
private static final Predicate<Object> removeDotPred = symbol -> !MULTI_ARGS_SIGNAL.equals(symbol);
```

В частности, интересно, что значит знак "->".

Answer (score 23):

В *Java 8* появились лямбда выражения.

Lambda-выражения – это что-то вроде анонимных функций. Если попроще — это метод без объявления, т.е. без модификаторов доступа, возвращающие значение и имя. Они позволяют написать метод и сразу же использовать его.

Lambda-выражения в *Java* обычно имеют следующий синтаксис

```
(аргументы) -> {тело}
```

Например:

```
(арг1, арг2...) -> { тело }     
(тип1 арг1, тип2 арг2...) -> { тело }
```

Далее идет несколько примеров настоящих Lambda-выражений:

```
(int a, int b) -> { return a + b; }     

() -> System.out.println("Hello World"); // Почему тут нет фигурных скобок - написано ниже

(String s) -> { System.out.println(s); } // Фигурные скобки в данном случае не обязательны

() -> 42  // Почему тут нет фигурных скобок - написано ниже 

() -> { return 3.1415 };
```

Структура lambda-выражений может быть разной:

- Lambda-выражения могут иметь от 0 и более входных параметров.
- Тип параметров можно указывать явно либо может быть получен из контекста. Например `(int a)` можно записать и так `(a)`
- Параметры заключаются в круглые скобки и разделяются запятыми.

  Пример: `(a, b)` или `(int a, int b)` или `(String a, int b, float c)`
- Если входных параметров нет, то нужно использовать пустые круглые скобки.

  Пример: `() -> 42`
- Когда параметр один, если тип не указывается явно, скобки можно опустить.

  Пример: `a -> return a*a`
- Тело Lambda-выражения может содержать от 0 и более выражений.
- Если тело состоит из одного оператора, его можно не заключать в фигурные скобки, а возвращаемое значение можно указывать без ключевого слова `return`.
- В противном случае фигурные скобки обязательны (блок кода), а в конце надо указывать возвращаемое значение с использованием ключевого слова `return` (в противном случае типом возвращаемого значения будет `void`).

---

В Вашем случае `symbol -> !MULTI_ARGS_SIGNAL.equals(symbol);` - это один входной параметр `symbol`, а тело состоит из одного оператора, а значит можно не указывать ключевое слово `return`, но оно подразумевается. По старому это будет как-то так:

```
public boolean Test(symbol) {
    return !MULTI_ARGS_SIGNAL.equals(symbol);
}
```

Comment: Алексей Шиманский,
Большое спасибо!

Comment: Да, еще хотел сказать.
С этими лямбда-выражениями я немного знаком из Python-а,
но не думал, что они перекочуют в Java.
Спасибо за обстоятельный и точный ответ.
Может пока не очень понятный, но теперь я буду знать, в какую сторону смотреть.
А то попадается в коде такая комбинация и не знаешь, шо и думать.
Еще раз, большое спасибо.

Comment: Класс!
Классный сайт!

Comment: @cap51 можно выразить признательность автору, пометив ответ как верный (галочка слева от ответа).