# Лямбда-выражения

Tags: java, lambda

Объясните простыми словами, что значит лямбда-выражение, (желательно, с показательным примером)? Что оно делает, другими словами. Сколько читаю, лазаю по всяким сайтам нигде не могу найти простого и понятного объяснения

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса [Синтаксис Java: “->” Лямбда выражения](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491121/191482)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Просто функция, которая неявно приводится к любому интерфейсу с единственным методом, причём имеющим ту же сигнатуру. Такой интерфейс называется функциональным.

Comment: @МиронФисенко, если всё понятно, следует принять ответ нажатием на галочку слева.

Answer (score 8):

С определение раз всё ясно, вот пример простой: кликаем по форме, сообщаем координаты клика. Без лямбд - определяем анонимный класс, переопределяющий метод handle. С лямбдами - одна лямбда, в которой содержится "тело" метода handle:

Без лямбд:

```
root.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Привет!" + e.getX() + ":" + e.getY());
            }
        });
```

С лямбдами:

```
root.setOnMousePressed((MouseEvent e) -> {
            System.out.println("Привет!" + e.getX() + ":" + e.getY());
        });
```

Или даже так:

```
root.setOnMousePressed((e)->{System.out.println("Привет!" + e.getX() + ":" + e.getY());});
```

С Runnable всё так же легко и просто:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(()->{System.out.println("Привет!");});
thread.start();
```

Или для отдачи задания в тред пул:

```
Runnable runnable = ()->{System.out.println("Привет!");};
```

Comment: В NetBeans удобно сделано преобразование из/в лямбды и обратно.