# что означает -> в Java

Tags: java

Подскажите где почитать о ->
Не пойму что это.

Comment: @Denis о спасибо добрый человек, за возможность закрыть миллионый вопрос на эту тему)

Comment: @Sergey уже был ответ на данный вопрос. Пожалуйста, пользуйтесь поиском... Если он работает))) http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491121/191482

Answer (score 0):

таким образом обозначается конструкция лямбда-функций, которые появились в Java8. Материала по этой теме много, например советую почитать [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/224593/)